# Crashes split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk and split_config.arm64_v8a.apk

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, crashlytics

I have updated android app with native libraries, that was build only for armeabi_v7 CPU architecture, and I added arm64 support after update.
App was written in cocos2d-x.
After update I started to get crashes in firebase crashlytics:

[image]

With empty stack trace:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here -

If you are building AABs and using Crashlytics NDK, you may have to try adding the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file, in your `<application/>` block:

```
<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    ...

</application>
```

This may not work for you, but we have seen it work with some developers. Note that this will increase the size of the final app binary that your end-users download.

Comment: But the default is `true` though

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to fix it?

Comment: any update on its fix?